SSL Pinning Android How to renew the pin set
We have SSL Pinning implementation in our android app. And we are changing certificate in next few months. So I would like to add new SHA-256 pin into config file.
> <domain-config>         
> <domain includeSubdomains="true">mywebsite.com</domain>         
> <pin-set>             
> <pin digest="SHA-256">34545dsfsgdsfdsfsewrtrerewrewrewrewrewrewrewew</pin>             
> <pin digest="SHA-256">2erewrewrczgfes=kdsfdsf=dgzf+fdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfd</pin>         
> </pin-set>     
> </domain-config>

Can we generate SHA-256 pin from certificate file ? and Is it ok to add new SHA-256 pin and old pin together so that app won't crash when new certificate is replaced in server?
